# animated 'waiting'-symbol in CLI mode

Tags: c, command-line-interface

I was wondering if someone knows a way to provide simple animations in the terminal. For instance, while processing a file, it would be nice to be able to show:

'|', '/', '-', '\', '|', etc.

at the same place with small time intervals in between, so it would look like a rotating bar (indicating the program is running).
The only way I know of doing this is by using ANSI escape characters or by using external libraries like ncurses.  I was wondering if there would be a better way to do this?

Comment: You may also like: [CLI progress bar](http://pastebin.com/RhZdBCUb) with your animated character as last block.

Answer (score 4):

At least as a first attempt, I'd try this:

```
static const char symbols[] = "|/-\\";

for (int i=0; i<10000; i++)
    printf("\r%c", symbols[i%4]);
```

Answer (score 3):

This is simply a modification on Jerry's code that should compile and run as-is.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

const char symbols[] = "|/-\\";
const int num_symbols = sizeof symbols - 1;

int main() {
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<25; i++) {
        printf("\r%c", symbols[i%num_symbols]);
        fflush(stdout);
        usleep(250000);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```